# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play') discord.js V14

Tags: discord, discord.js, null, typeerror

I'm trying to work on my play command for discord.js version 14. The package I'm using is **discord-player**. I have try many ways but seem to get stuck with the same error.... Below is my command code. Thank you...

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { player } = require('discord-player');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Given a youtube link, plays the song/playlist.',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'query',
            description: 'Link to the song/playlist or name to play',
            type: 3,
            required: true,
        },
    ],
    run: async(client, interaction, args) => {
    const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;
    if (!channel)
      return interaction.followUp({ content: "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!", ephemeral: true });
      const query = interaction.options.getString('query', true);

      //await interaction.deferReply();

      try {
          const { track } = await player.play(channel, query, {
              nodeOptions: {
                  metadata: interaction.channel,
              }
          });
  
          return interaction.followUp(`**${track.title}** enqueued!`);
      } catch (e) {
          return interaction.followUp(`Something went wrong: ${e}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

If you need the event code its below

```js
const client = require('../../index')

client.on("playerStart", (queue, track) => {
    queue.metadata.channel.send(`Started playing **${track.title}**!`);
})
```

Thank you

I try removing track but didn't work...

```js
      try {
           await player.play(channel, query, {
              nodeOptions: {
                  metadata: interaction.channel,
              }
          });
  
          return interaction.followUp(`Loading Music.....`);
      } catch (e) {
          return interaction.followUp(`Something went wrong: ${e}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. It should be `const { Player } = require('discord-player');` and you should instantiate it first. Check the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-player